# How to get video from livestream and pass it to local web without crossorigin

Tags: node.js, angular, video-streaming, live

Sooo basicly i have this link: 'https://randomTvApiLink/.smil/playlist.m3u8?tokenhash=3kjc-AWPAdtYKW_ehngzV-Jsuuib2Jp_Iz8jpAmsB4rSP7CJ5sBBVU0wFD3Vg2lkjTLX_IuQTQ==&tokenendtime=1561905282'

ofc its not a real link, but when you enter it you get a .m3u8 file so you can watch live video

The thing is i tried using it on my angular 6 app front end this link but when i want to watch it it drops me a crossorigin problem because it calls video from localhost:4200

is there a way using nodejs or angular 6 it self to get that data and without cross origin pass it to front end?

NEED HELP PLEASE

Comment: Why did you repost this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825517/need-help-handling-downloadable-livestream-file-on-angular2

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is pipe the request from your server to your client. Check the code below -

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const app = express()

const URL = '<Some video link>'


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const request = https.get(URL, function(response) {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);
    response.pipe(res);
  });

  request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
  });

  request.end();
})

app.listen(8080 , () => {
  console.log(`Server running on 8080`)
})
```